# Wait in Cypress custom comand for response value to change

Tags: cypress, response, wait, polling

What is the best solution for polling response until value in response change from 'WAITING' to 'RUNNING'. So recursive function is not solution, because I don't want to send more than 1 request.

```js
Cypress.Commands.add('createService', () => {
  const query = '';
  cy.request({
   method: 'POST',
      url: 'http://localhost:3000/create',
      body: {
        query
      }
  }).then((response){
     //before RUNNING status is WAITING
    expect(response.body.serviceStatus).to.eql('RUNNING');
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`cypress-recurse`](https://github.com/bahmutov/cypress-recurse) for your situation.

```js
import { recurse } from 'cypress-recurse'

recurse (
  cy.request({
     method: 'POST',
     url: 'http://localhost:3000/create',
     body: { query }
  }), // actions you want to iterate
  response.body.serviceStatus == 'RUNNING', // until this condition is satisfied  
  { // options to pass along
      log: true,
      limit: 50, // max number of iterations
      timeout: 30000, // time limit in ms
      delay: 300, // delay before next iteration, ms
  }
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You **cannot** poll a `cy.request()` because it only ever replies with a **single** response.

If that response is 'WAITING', the test will not receive another response. You would have to resend the request.

Answer (score 0):

You can apply a `should('equal', 'RUNNING')` assertion with a custom timeout. The should assertion will re-try for the specified amount of time for the expected value `RUNNING`. Currently the timeout is 6000ms(6 seconds) but you can change it to whatever works for your case.

```js
Cypress.Commands.add('createService', () => {
  const query = ''
  cy.request({
    method: 'POST',
    url: 'http://localhost:3000/create',
    body: {
      query,
    },
  }).as('req')

  cy.wait('@req')
    .its('response.body.serviceStatus', {timeout: 6000})
    .should('equal', 'RUNNING')
})
```

Answer (score 0):

HTTP is only single response, but the original POST can give you a status of 202 and a header to poll.

```js
const poll = (url, attempts = 0) => {
  if (attempts > 20) throw 'Too many attempts'

  cy.request(url).then(response => {
    if (response.body.serviceStatus !== "RUNNING") {
      cy.wait(1000)  // throttle if desired
      poll(url, ++attempts)
  })
}

cy.request({
  method: 'POST',
  url: 'http://localhost:3000/create',
  body: {
    query
  }
}).then((response){

  if (response.status === 202) {
    poll(response.headers.location)
  } else {
    expect(response.body.serviceStatus).to.eq('RUNNING')
  }
})
```

Answer (score -1):

You should use an intercept/wait combination:

```
cy.intercept({
    method: 'POST',
    hostname: 'http://localhost:3000/create'
}).as('checkStatus');


cy.wait('@checkStatus').then((interception) => {
    expect(interception.response.body.serviceStatus).to.be.eq('RUNNING');
})
```

Above should work whether you make a single request or you make multiple requests, since the cy.wait command will intercept any call defined in the 'checkStatus' intercept function.

Comment: Nope, you cannot intercept a `cy.request()` command.

Comment: Sure you can, we have above implemented in our test suite and works great.

Comment: Definitely cannot use intercept to catch cy.request, only requests from the app. It's pretty easy to confirm it with a minimal test.